# Can I marry Ysolda?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Ok, so I like Ysolda more than any of the other women in the game Skyrim, and I really wanted to have her as my wife on the game.  However, I don't know if that is possible, or how to initiate the marriage dialogue if it is.  Little help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Ysolda to become available you must complete the sidequest she gives you to fetch a mammoth tusk.

You must also have spoken to Maramal in Riften about conducting weddings to allow marriage in general.

After doing these two things you simply need to speak to her while wearing an Amulet of Mara and follow through the dialogue.

Comment: Thank you!  I can't get her to give me the sidequest, though... any ideas?

Comment: @Horus The quest is [Rare Gifts](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Rare_Gifts). Note that "Only one "Rare Gifts" quest can be active at a given time, quest dialogue will not show up with the other characters if another "Rare Gifts" quest is active." So make sure you don't have another one of those active.